# plot a windrose in a map using lon,lat coordinates

Tags: r, gis

I have two matrix with the u and v components of geostrophic current in the ocean. The matrix are 240x242, rows being longitude points and columns latitude points. I would like to plot a windrose inside a map following an equidistant grid (for example, each 5 grid points)using the lon,lat coordinates. I have tried with windrose (circular) and windRose (openair package), without any success. Is this possible? I checked this forum and couldn't find an answer for my issue. 
Thanks a lot.

```
#R version: 3.4.4
library(maps) # maps ver. 3.3.0
library(openair) # openair ver. 2.4-2
library(circular) # circular ver. 0.4-93

#Geographic coordinates
lats <- seq(18, 30, 3)
lons <- seq(-98, -86, 3)
lonlats <- expand.grid(lons, lats)

#simulate some current (or wind) data: dir is direction, spd is speed or 
#magnitude.data are arrays of dimension longitudexlatitudex50, where the 
#third dimension contains a timeseries of each (lon,lat) pair.
arr.dir <- array(sample(1:360, 1250, replace=T), dim = c(5,5,50))
arr.spd <- array(sample(0:140, 1250, replace=T), dim = c(5,5,50))

#visualize grid in a map
plot(lonlats$Var1, lonlats$Var2, xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude", 
asp=1, pch=19)
map(database = "world", add=T, fill=T, col="gray"); box()

#windroses for the time series at (-86,30), at the right upper corner of 
#the map.

#with circular
rose1 <- data.frame(dir=circular(arr.dir[5,5,], units="degrees", 
template="geographics"), mag=arr.spd[5,5,])

windrose(rose1)

#with openair
windRose(mydata = data.frame(ws=arr.spd[5,5,], wd=arr.dir[5,5,]), 
paddle=F)

#### question: how do I plot one of the roses (preferablly with openair) 
#in the map, at the corresponding coordinates? ####
```

Comment: Please share your data and code so others can help. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have edited my question, adding reproducible code. Thank you.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/47116898/786542

Comment: Thank you. I would really prefer a "r base" approach, I tried to work with ggplot and my bosses weren't very excited about it. I have to stick to a format that uses simple mapping. Cheers.

Comment: Of course, why use best practices.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?